# オフィスからAWSに接続するために必要な機器と情報について

Tags: aws

**■実現したい事**
AWSのEC2サービスを使用してクラウド上にサーバーを1台構築し、オフィスにオンプレで構築したサーバー1台とHULFTでファイル授受を行う

**■現状の知識と状況**
ネットワーク知識は初心者レベル。（ネットで調べた程度）
実際の構築経験無し。
実現するための大まかな構成を検討して絵を書いている状態。

**■知りたい事**
上記を実現するにあたり、どんな機器や情報を用意すればいいのか、調べてもよく理解できませんでした。

**【AWS側】**
AWS側は、おそらくクラウドサービスとして接続するための設定手順が存在するのかと思います。
わからないなりに調べたところ、AWSのネットワークサービスは主に3つあり、今回は「VPN接続」を採用する想定です。
VPCを作成し、その窓口にVGWを作るイメージになるのかと思います。
クラウドなので機器の用意は必要ないと思っていますが、設定を行うにあたり、どんな情報を用意すればいいでしょうか。
（自社のシステム担当にグローバルIPを払い出してもらうとか？）

**【オフィス側】**
用意するべき機器と情報が不明。
窓口としてVPNサーバー機能を持ったL3ルータが必要？
回線は既設のインターネットにアクセスできる回線があればいいのか、別途回線契約が必要なのか。
オフィス内のサーバやクライアントからL3ルータまでの接続はどのような構成になるのか。
L2スイッチが必要？
NAT変換が必要？

まとまりが無く申し訳ありませんが、経験が無く、知識が断片化している状況です。
回答するに不足している情報もあるかと思いますので、ご指摘いただけると助かります。

Comment: 質問内容からすると回答内容が多いので回答が難しくなります。まずはHULFTをからどのような接続がいるか記載したほうが良いかと思います。HULFT（社内サーバー）からはAWSへの接続は「HTTP接続（WebDAV）」もしくは「ファイルシステム（￥￥サーバー名の形式）」でしょうか？それを決めてからAWS・社内NWの開けるポートが決まります。

Answer (score 0):

シンプルに描いてみては如何でしょう。少し乱暴に書きますが。

オンプレということは社内NW(以下、社内イントラ)と仮定します。
クラウド(AWS)は社外NW(以下、インターネット)ですかね。

社内イントラからインターネットに接続するには、ほぼプロキシサーバ経由の接続となります。
※色々割愛します
プロキシサーバを超えるにはファイアウォール(以下FW)を経由します。
FWを経由するには約束事が必要です。
　FW:"どこから来た誰?(ホスト名/FQDN)、何しに来たの?(プロトコル。httpとかftpとか)、で何処に行くの?(ポート:80とか20、21とか)。"
　FW:"少し待って。確認する。ok、通りな。"

難しく考えずに、
　社内イントラから社外NWに接続したい。FWの定義変更(≒FW穴あけ)をしてもらいたい。
と御社のシステム担当の方に聞いてみてはどうでしょうか。
前例や知見があれば御社のシステム担当者から回答がくると思います。

L2,3レイヤーやNAT-IPの有無の必要性はその解答から得られると思います。

以上です。